# TortoiseSVN import - can't authenticate?

Tags: svn, import, tortoisesvn

I am trying to create a new project on my SUBVERSION repository.

So, I've got my files on my local machine:

```
C:\projects\myProject
```

Right click on myProject folder, then I choose ***TORTOISE SVN -> Import...***

In the *URL of repository* i put:

```
https://my.svn.server/myProject
```

*Note: myProject does not exist yet in my repository, as far as I understand the import command should create this new project and commit everything from myProject folder as version 0*

Then i click OK. TortoiseSVN promts for login and password.

**I put my login and password**  *(which I am sure is correct, becouse I use it to update/commit to another project in this repository)* **and.. it promts me again.. so I put it again in.. and again.. until after 5 tries I get error:**

```
OPTIONS of 'https://my.svn.server/myProject': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://my.svn.server)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

I am trying to log in with a user/password that works for my other repository/project (that is on the same server). I assumed that SUBVERSION users work for all repositories on the serwer.

If that assumtion is wrong, please point me: where can I add new user info for SUBVERSION repository?

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you're using `import` in a wrong direction. IIRC, `import` is used on the server to import a bunch of files directly.

The way you're using it, you try to import the contents of `https://my.svn.server/myProject` (which is the repo, if I'm right) into your working copy (`C:\projects\myProject`).

What you probably want is:

```
svn checkout https://my.svn.server/myProject C:/projects/myProject
svn add [your files here]
svn commit
```

---

**EDIT:**
If you just created a new repo on the server, you probably have to edit the `conf/authz` file to be able to access the repo:

```
[/path/to/project]
your_username = rw
@readonly_group = r
```

Comment: Well, to clarify what I am trying to do:

I have a project let's call it: **projectA** and my login/password are working for all update/commit/browse etc commands for this project.

Now I've created a new project (by svnadmin create /path/to/project command) on my SERVER.

On my local machine (which is not the same machine as the server) I left click a folder with files and I use TortoiseSVN->Checkout.

And my login/pass is incorrect. Why? Where do I need to add my user (on the server) info to login?

Comment: it didn't help

i've compared my **projectA** files with the newly created repository and in **projectA** in the authz file there is no user added

in my **projectA** repository i see nowhere any user added _(but.. it's working.. so thats why i assumed that this user is not user-for-repository but a more global user-for-the-whole-subversion-server)_

Answer (score 0):

Did you try accessing that URL with a web browser first? You can try out your login and password that way.

If it doesn't work, then contact the administrator of your Subversion repository and reconfirm your login details.